# Black on black flag indicator

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, css

The flag indicator is black-on-black. The text is visible, but the indicator is not very noticeable.

[image]

Comment: This exists on other sites too, like Meta.SO. There is [a related post there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212372/top-bar-should-be-consistent-on-all-sites-but-its-not).

Comment: I keep thinking there are no flags because of this. :D

Comment: ♫ There are no flags in the workplace, and the streets are paved with cheese ♫

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have rolled out a consistent color scheme for suggested edit and flag indicators in global top bar. Flag will be orange and suggested edits be in dark maroon color background. This change will go out after the next production build.

Comment: There is a [meta thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223085/) asking for them to be changed again. Just if anyone wants to see.